# Thread can't access datagrid source collection

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, performance, datagrid

The plan: Get lots of data from a serial port and display it on screen

The problem: SerialPort.dataReceived runs on a different thread than the UI thread and UI thread seems to own the datagrids source aswell. That means that i can't just add to the list directly in my serial port thread. My solution to this problem was to create a static class that acts as my "Database" and my serial port thread gives its data to that class. Then in my UI thread i get that data and copy it to the UI threads list and that works but it sucks.

This is pretty much the problem:

```
LocalRawDataCollection.Clear();
for( int i = 0; i < Database.GetRawDataCollection().Count; i++)
{
    LocalRawDataCollection.Add(Database.GetRawDataItem(i));
}
RawDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Sience i do this 3 times every time i want to refresh my data grid the program gets super slow.
Ideally i would just do:

```
LocalRawDataCollection = Database.getRawDataCollection();
```

But when i did that the data didn't show up on my screen.

One solution would be to separate the grids and rest of the UI so i would in a way have 2 UI threads. This wouldnt help my datagrid but atleast i could use the rest of my window well. I don't understand how i would make that and i couldn't find any good documents for doing that.

Is there anyway i could do this better?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @Clemens Thanks! that was exactly what i was looking for.